# How to get a ruby syntax highlighting in IntelliJ IDEA Community 12

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea

I know that there is no "official" support from Jetbrains. How can I workaround this?
I just need a syntax highlighting level of support for ruby.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow the instructions in this blog post:
http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/09/custom-file-types-in-intellij-idea/

I've followed that process myself to setup custom syntax highlighting for both Velocity Template Language and JavaScript files, and am just about to do the same for Ruby.

Comment: Perfect! There is a way to define an icon for a new file type?

Answer (score -3):

Sure there is [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/company/contacts/) an official technical support.

You can find `ruby` plugin for `IntellJ IDEA` [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/ruby_rails.html%60)

Btw, first I thought you were using `RubyMine`, there you can set the auto-completion by going to File | Settings - IDE Settings - Editor - Code completion, so you could try to find what's up in this path for `IntelliJ IDEA`

Comment: I'm referring to the Community Edition. This plugin won't work in my IDEA because they are incompatible.